# Comment or up vote an other question as a noob

Tags: discussion

This issue is the exact one I get, but it has not been answered:
[Entity Framework stored procedure: Function Import to Complex Type, Error on Get Column Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584455/entity-framework-stored-procedure-function-import-to-complex-type-error-on-get)

I would want up vote it, or something else to show it's still an issue, and to comment on it with my own additions.

Is there any way to do this without reputation, or should I just post a duplicate question linking to that one?

This is not a duplicate of [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions) as this is for someone else's question, not my own. This means I can't edit the issue with more info, as the edit will just get rejected with the comment "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." That is correct, but I can't reply/comment because of no rep.

Comment: you can offer a bounty on the question to get attention.

Comment: @mehow He can't do that either. Needs at least 75 reps.

Comment: I noticed a few minor issues with the post so I've edited it. This will bump it which may get it a little more attention

Comment: @RichardTingle does it still bump the question even if you're more than 2k?

Comment: @mehow O yes, we can't be trusted either. Plus it makes sense. My edit was relatively minor (capitalisation and such) but it could have made the post clearer in which case giving it more attention makes sense

Comment: I've suggested an edit, so it should have been bumped. I also gave an upvote since it looks like a good question (although I admit I'm not an expert at those technologies at all)

Answer (score 7):

Please don't do that. Be patient and earn reputation by

1. suggesting good edits (+2)
2. answering questions well (+10 per upvote and +15 if the OP accepts)
3. asking great questions (+5 per upvote)